# May I start a paragraph "Being born and brought up in India..."?

Tags: grammar

Is the phrase "Being born and brought up in India.. " correct usage? It is at the start of the paragraph

Comment: Yes, seems like a perfectly correct usage. Of course, providing that the rest of the sentence is structured in a right way.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48164/can-i-say-i-was-born-in-a-place-but-bred-in-another-place-instead-of-using-bo

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's fine.

However, the more common idiom is "I was born and raised in India" (or wherever).

"Brought up in India" would usually be used without the word "born".

I'm speaking of American English here. I don't know if Indian English would be different on this point.

Comment: I do think *born and brought up* is particularly common in Indian English.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be looking for a sentence-leading dependent clause.  In that case, "having been born and raised" sounds more natural.  For example:

> Having been born and raised in India, I am fluent in Hindi.